# Hide the button of a JComboBox if is !enabled

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I would like to extends JComboBox class no change something, I want the new component to hide the selection button when the combobox is disabled.

I can't find where this button is created

**EDIT** : so far I am using this code :

```
@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean b)
{
    super.setEnabled(b);

    Component[] comps = getComponents();
    for(Component comp : comps)
    {
        if(comp instanceof MetalComboBoxButton)
        {
            final MetalComboBoxButton dropDownButton = (MetalComboBoxButton) comp;
            dropDownButton.setVisible(b);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2** : I was unable to do what I want finally, as if I switch to Nimbus PLAF, even if I hide the button the background is drawn, so only the arrow is hidded, everything else is still there.

I will have to do with a JPanel.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I don't get the point.

Comment: The dropdown button that permit to select items, I want it to not be displayed when the combobox is disabled (user can't click this drop down button, so want to hide it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

technically, you can subclass the JComboBox and either remove/add the button (as shown by @flash) or toggle its visibility

```
    final JComboBox box = new JComboBox(new Object[] {1, 2, 3}) {

        /** 
         * @inherited <p>
         */
        @Override
        public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
            if (b == isEnabled()) return;
            for (Component child : getComponents()) {
                if (child instanceof JButton) {
                    child.setVisible(b);
                    break;
                }
            }
            super.setEnabled(b);
        }

    };
```

You might want to reconsider the requirement, though, because it is non-standard ui behaviour - and as such might confuse users

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I can't change that, it is a project requirement, and is part of a dialog loaded in configuration mode (editable) or consultation mode (not editable -> hidding the button)

Comment: As a side note, if you plan on doing that often you might want to save the reference of `child` for further use.

Comment: @Matthieu technically, sure - but its bad style to keep references to thingies that might change without listening to a potential change (though here the probability for a changeis not very high :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
public class CustomCombo extends JComboBox {

@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
    if(!enabled) {
        removeArrowButton();
    }
    else {
        addArrowButton();         
    }
}

private void removeArrowButton() {
    Component[] comp = this.getComponents();
    Component removeComponent = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < comp.length; i++) {
        if(comp[i] instanceof JButton) {
            removeComponent = comp[i];
        }
    }
    if(removeComponent != null) {
        this.remove(removeComponent);
    }
}
}
```

This will remove the arrow button when you call `customCombo.setEnabled(false)`.

The method `addArrowButton()` is left up to you. This should just give you an idea.

Comment: not remove, never ever, success with setVisible() or best of all to setIcon()

Comment: Great, this is a good start, now I have to find how to update the text field because hidding / removing this button let an empty box ;)

Comment: the remove is incomplete: you have to store the removed button for later re-adding.

Answer (score 0):

You may have trouble finding it because you're looking in wrong place - try `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.installComponents()` and `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.configureArrowButton()`

Comment: I tried to change the way to do it, by extending BasicComboBoxUI, but I loose the UI, how can I do ? class JComboVStringUI extends BasicComboBoxUI{public void setEnabled(boolean enabled){arrowButton.setVisible(enabled);}}